# Taking "ten" values from a textbox, splitting them into 10 single values and outputting into a column

Tags: vb.net, text, mapping

I am currently using a modified version of the Below code to send information entered in combo boxs and textboxs on Form 2.
into Labels Form3

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim f As New FormVb2()
f.TextBox1Value = TextBox1.Text
f.ShowDialog()
End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form2
Public Property TextBox1Value As String

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1Value
End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks to @steven Doggart,

I am now looking to take this process a little further....
Lets say textbox5 on form 2 has the following data...
27, 34, 56, 94, 23
I want this data to be taken into Form3
and output on 5 differnt labels as
27
34
56
94
23

The problems i am thinking straight away is will i need labels in place ready to input these into (if the data can be split) or can it be coded to create and place the data?
as the form2 has 10 text boxs and each of these could have 1 to 50 differnet values input, and i would want it to take the data from each textbox on form2, output them as individual values on form3 in a column.

If i ever hit 15rep i can put up some screenshots that will help show this process a little better
Any further info needed, please let me know.

Thanks alot in advance for your advice/help/suggestions!

Comment: where did you have your Form2 and Form3 inside a mdi container.? or what.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting the data is certainly possible, but it all depends on the actual format of the data.  If the data is always formatted with a comma followed by a space between each value, then you can use the `String.Split` method, like this:

```
Dim data As String = "27, 34, 56, 94, 23"
Dim values() As String = data.Split({", "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

The `String.Split` method returns an array of strings where each item in the array is one of the delimited values.

As far as displaying them on a `Form`, if you want to display them in a column of `Label` controls, you would need to create a new `Label` for each item in the array.  Either you would need to have them already on the form, from design-time, or you would need to dynamically instantiate the `Label` controls at run-time.  Neither is an option that I would recommend, however.  If you need to display a column of data, there are better controls to use for that sort of thing than a `Label`.

I would recommend using a `ListBox` control to display them.  The advantage of the `ListBox` control, besides convenience, is that it can display any number of items.  If there are too many items to fit in the control, it will show a scroll bar so the user can scroll up and down through the items.  Here's how you could fill a `ListBox` from the string array:

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(values)
```

Alternatively, if you really need to use a `Label` control, for some reason, you could display each item on a separate line in a single Label control.  To do that, you'd need to join all of the items together using the `NewLine` string as the delimiter, for instance:

```
Label1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, values)
```

Raja provided an excellent example of how to loop through all the `TextBox` controls on the form and build an `ArrayList` containing all of their split values.  I would caution you, however,  that it will find *ALL* `TextBox` controls on the form, so if you have any other text boxes, you will need to alter the logic a little bit.  My only real suggestion to improve upon what he did is, instead of using an `ArrayList`, you should be using a `List(Of String)`.  The `ArrayList` is not type-specific, so it's less safe, and is therefore not recommended.  It's an older class from the early days of .NET, back before generics were supported.  Now-a-days, even if you need a type-unspecific list, most people recommend using `List(Of Object)` rather than `ArrayList`.

To build a list of the strings from multiple text boxes, and then add them to a `ListBox`, you can do this:

```
Dim allValues As New List(Of String)()
For Each i As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
    allValues.AddRange(i.Text.Split({", "}, StringSplitOptions.None))
Next
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(allValues.ToArray())
```

Comment: Loving the idea of the arraylist rather than having to output every single vale to a label, would make my life alot easier!
Will try and incorporate this once i have managed to get the example above to work

Comment: How would i edit the last section

 For Each XText In mValues

            Me.Controls.Add(New Label() With _
                                 { _
                                 .Name = xVal, _
                                 .Text = XText, _
                                 .Location = New Point(296, xVal) _
                                 }) : xVal += 15
to input to an List instead? or is it like the orignal where i just say ListBox1.Items(text?) = xText

Comment: Only just gor round to trying to implement this, trying to use this to colletc in form 2, output in form3, and i am getting the following error 'Split' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)' when just using the above code in one form without trying to drag across forms

Comment: Got the above working, i am using 2 list 1 grabs combo boxs and 1 grabs text boxs' puts them itno 2 differnt Listbox's however.... the first textbox and the first combo box's data get put like 3/4 down the list. however the remaining data gets put at the top in a list as expected...

Answer (score 1):

I just edited your code and made a `snippet` that suits your reqiurement.

**Form1:**

```
Public Class Form1

 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

       Dim xFrm2 = New FormVb2

       'This loop will get the text from all of your text boxes, split that with ','
       'and after that it will add that text into the public arraylist of form2

       For Each xTextBoxes In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
          xFrm2.mValues.AddRange(xTextBoxes.Text.Split(","))
       Next

       xFrm2.ShowDialog()

 End Sub

End Class
```

**Form2:**

```
Public Class Form2

 Public mValues As New ArrayList

    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

           Dim xVal As Integer = 0

           'This loop will get values from that list and create a new label for each. 
           'Here i had set some other properties, for a visual representation.
           For Each XText In mValues

              Me.Controls.Add(New Label() With _
                                   { _
                                   .Name = xVal, _
                                   .Height = 50, _
                                   .Text = XText, _
                                   .Location = New Point(0, xVal), _
                                   .BackColor = If((xVal / 10) Mod 2 = 0, Color.Red, Color.White) _
                                   }) : xVal +=50

           Next

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Currently trying to merge both answers together, I like the idea of the Listbox being used to hold all data. but still struggling with the initial set up above, My anmes to vary to what i used in my example (my bad) the actual code i had in place was more like...
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
         Dim f As New Form3()
         f.TextBox1Value = TextBox1.Text
         f.textBox2Value = TextBox2.Text
         f.ShowDialog()
      End Sub
i had alot of box's so the loop would work a treat